# Apache Lucene Sort Issues with GAE-Lucene addDocuments

Tags: java, google-app-engine, lucene

I have been trying to get Sort working for Apache Lucene and Google App Engine. I am using the https://github.com/UltimaPhoenix/luceneappengine to integrate Luncene in GAE. Here is what I am doing

1. I have a list of Documents, which I am putting into Lucene using the IndexWriter using addDocuments() method.

   ```
   for(Object object : objects) {
       Document doc = new Document();
       document.add(new Field("id", generateDocId(object), idType));
       document.add(new NumericDocValuesField("sortLong",<Long Value>));
       documents.add(doc)
   }
   ```

   I am basically aggregating all the documents into a list and writing to index using

   ```
   IndexWriter writer = getWriter();
   writer.addDocuments(documents);
   ```
2. I am trying to query a few documents, based on some Query as well as Sort

   ```
   Sort sort = new Sort(new SortField("sortLong", SortField.Type.LONG, true));
   TopFieldDocs docs = searcher.search(new MatchAllDocsQuery(),2000,sort);
   ```

Problem:

When I use addDocuments to bulk index the documents, my Sort Queries are not returning the data in the correct Sort Order, basically they are wrong, however if I index each document using addDocument(), the Sort Queries are working correctly.

This has led me to deduce that there is something inherently wrong with addDocuments().  The sort wont work unless, I open the indexWriter, addDocument and Close the indexWriter. Which I am unwilling to do, because I have may thousands of records to index.

Is there any solution for this problem? Or is it a known defect.

Comment: It seems to be working correctly to me.  Here's a runnable example:  https://gist.github.com/femtorgon/ab31099edc0e9bb86f68de31474abdf8   I think more information might be necessary to reproduce the problem.  Perhaps there is some other difference at work between the version using `addDocuments` and the version using `addDocument` in a loop?

Comment: It works for RAMDirectory, SimpleFSDirectory, etc. It specifically fails in case of GaeDirectory from the luceneappengine project.